use of undeclared identifier 'FBSDKApplicationDelegate'
I'm trying to integrate fbsdk on my react native app but whenever i add the fbsdk on my appdelegate, im encountering this issue
I've tried to add -Swift, but there are also issues. I've also tried to fix the issue regarding the -Swift but still can't fix it. I've tried almost everything I can think of to fix this issue but still error
Here is my appdelegate.mm
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"main";

  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};

  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  return [self getBundleURL];
}

- (NSURL *)getBundleURL
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@".expo/.virtual-metro-entry"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

// Linking API
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                openURL:url
                                                      sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKeySourceApplication]
                                                             annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKeyAnnotation]];

  return handled || [super application:application openURL:url options:options] || [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

// Universal Links
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
  BOOL result = [RCTLinkingManager application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
  return [super application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler] || result;
}

// Explicitly define remote notification delegates to ensure compatibility with some third-party libraries
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  return [super application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

// Explicitly define remote notification delegates to ensure compatibility with some third-party libraries
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  return [super application:application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}

// Explicitly define remote notification delegates to ensure compatibility with some third-party libraries
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  return [super application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

@end


Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75930402/833395

the issue is still there :(

Would you add  code of your import statement and related code in app delegate ?

I've edited my post, kindly check, thank you

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/75930402/833395
